# How to pull a section of text from a word document within Blue Prism

Tags: automation, blueprism, rpa

within blue prism once a word document has been attached and opened with all data being stored to a Data Item, which string utility would be best to take specific sections of text from the Data Item and store it into a collection ?

Comment: If the text you want to extract follows a certain pattern, you could extract the text of the document to a data item, then use the `Utility - Strings` business object to apply a group-capture regular expression.

Comment: Hello Esqew, what expression would be needed to extract a specific section of the text stored within a data item ?

Comment: The expression would change depending on how you could isolate the data you're interested in. [Microsoft Regex Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

if your text doesn't follow a certain pattern you can highlight the text in your document and extract the text using "Get Highlighted Text" action.

This is advisable only if you are developing an attended bot and your text document doesn't  conform to a pattern

Comment: The document does follow a pattern and the data I need will always start with the same words. Would there be a way to scan for a certain word and pull x amount of characters after this, storing it into a data item ?